# select 2 columns from table where columns from comboboxes

Tags: c#, sql

how to select 2 columns from 2comboboxes from table1 and put the data in these 2 columns in in listview11 in button1 click event

I tried this but didn't work nothing is added to listview1

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (cn.State == ConnectionState.Closed) cn.Open();
        cm.Connection = cn;
        if (comboBox3.Enabled == true)
        {
            string searchFor2 = comboBox1.Text;
            string searchFor3 = comboBox2.Text;
            string selectSql = "SELECT " + searchFor2 + ", " + searchFor3 + " FROM itmsparts";
            SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(selectSql, cn);
            try
            {
                using (SqlDataReader read1 = com.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    using (SqlDataReader read1 = com.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (read1.Read())
                    {
                        ListViewItem parent = listView1.Items.Add(read1[0].ToString());
                        parent.SubItems.Add(read1[1].ToString());
                    }
                }
                }
            }
            finally
            {

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Define "didn't work".  Was there an error?  Was the resulting query what you expected it to be?  How did it fail?

Comment: I think you want the SelectedValue, and not the Text of the combobox

Comment: Did you try debug for the value of `selectSql ` and try that direct on the db?

Comment: thanks for your reply @DavidP but can u edit my code so that I can understand better

Comment: read1["searchFor2"] - it mean it trying to search the column with name as `searchFor2` but actually you dont have such column use the index 0,1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
using (SqlDataReader read1 = com.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (read1.Read())
                    {
                        ListViewItem parent = listView1.Items.Add(read1[0].ToString());
                        parent.SubItems.Add(read1[1].ToString());
                    }
                }
```

had to change that part and it's working :)

Answer (score 0):

You cant use `read1["searchFor2"]` to get the field name

Try:

```
foreach (ListViewItem item in listView1.Items)
  {
     item.Text = (read1[0].ToString());
     item.SubItems[1].Text = (read1[1].ToString());
  }
```

Comment: thanks for your answer @juan .. but still nothing is added to the listview .. the values in columns are not added to listview1

Comment: @user5456980 if still not added then specify the error and make it sure you have some data in table

Comment: can you show me what is inside your `selectSql ` variable before the `new SqlCommand(selectSql, cn);`

Comment: check the edit .. that's all I have in my button click event

Comment: I say when you press the button do a debug stop to see what is the value of the string

Answer (score 0):

when you say

> > read1["searchFor2"]

it means it will try to search the column with the name of 'searchFor2' you need to remove the double quotes.

```
item.Text = (read1[searchFor2].ToString());
item.SubItems[1].Text = (read1[searchFor3].ToString());
```

Comment: still no items added .. the columns names I selected in comboboxes should be searched for in the table and add items in these columns Into listview1

Comment: then I dont see any issue with the code. it seems good to me.  check ur table has some values. and debug the code and check where is failing.